# Device is not Bluetooth qualified by SIG, how can I provide technical guidance without violating Qualification Enforcement?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Say I have a product that is not Bluetooth qualified. Assuming there is something inherent in the physical device preventing qualification, is it possible for me to advise engineers on how to utilize the Bluetooth Protocol with this product without violating [qualification enforcement](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/qualification-enforcement-program/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Bluetooth SIG are quite strict about the Bluetooth Qualification process. This means that if there is a mandatory feature that is not implemented/not supported, then the only way is to add support for this feature or implement it properly. The only alternatives are if 1) The feature is not mandatory, or 2) You end up not using the Bluetooth technology or logo (although this will end up being a challenging path during the normal regulatory approval process).

Some useful links about the subjects:-

- [Bluetooth Qualification Process Overview](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/)
- [Proof of Quality for the Compatibility of Bluetooth Products](https://www.cetecom.com/en/certification/bluetooth-sig-certification/)
- [Most Common Bluetooth Qualification Mistakes to Avoid](https://collateral-library-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/asset_file/attachment/26942/The_most_common_Bluetooth_Qualification_mistakes_to_avoid_DIGITAL_OK.pdf)

Finally, please note that StackOverflow is for programming related questions. For similar questions in the future, I recommend [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). You also have [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for information security related questions, and [network.stackexchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) for network/communications related questions.